# Run playbook on servers with shared NFS mount

Tags: permissions, ansible, nfs

I have the following Ansible playbook to do package updates across a cluster:

```
- hosts: cluster
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: updates a server
     apt: update_cache=yes
   - name: upgrade a server
     apt: upgrade=full
```

When I run it, the node that is the NFS controller executes just fine, but the two nodes that have an NFS mount on the home directory fails with the following error:

```
$ansible-playbook upgrade-servers.yml  -K
SUDO password:

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [nej-worker2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "\r\n/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/gms/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461269057.4-144211747884693/setup': [Errno 13] Permission denied\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
ok: [iznej]
fatal: [nej-worker1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "\r\n/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/home/gms/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461269057.4-16590584976890/setup': [Errno 13] Permission denied\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

TASK [updates a server] ********************************************************
ok: [iznej]

TASK [upgrade a server] ********************************************************
changed: [iznej]

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
iznej                      : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
nej-worker1                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
nej-worker2                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I've had similar issues running `pip` on the shares, with the fix being to redirect the build directory using `--set-build`... I am assuming this is the problem with Ansible, since it is working on the NFS controller and not the ones with the servers with the shared/mounted drive.

Answer (score 4):

Got it. Needed to add remote_tmp = /tmp/.ansible to my ansible.cfg file. See here [Ansible config parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#remote-tmp) Voila!

The issue is that when Ansible executes sudo, the root account is NOT a user account on the NFS mounted shares.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting RHEL 6 Security Guide:

> "By default, NFS shares change the root user to the nfsnobody user, an
>   unprivileged user account. This changes the owner of all root-created
>   files to nfsnobody, which prevents uploading of programs with the
>   setuid bit set. If no_root_squash [option] is used, remote root users
>   are able to change any file on the shared file system and leave
>   applications infected by Trojans for other users to inadvertently
>   execute."

In other words, this is a default and secure NFS behavior.